# Connect buttons to operations in calculator built on Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

We are tasked with creating a calculator in tkinter and have trouble clearing values from the calculator as well as using buttons to perform operations: addition(x,y) subtraction(x,y) product(x,y) division(x,y).  I would appreciate any help to solve my problem and improve my code:

```
from tkinter import*
n1=0
n2=0
operator=''

win=Tk()
frame=Frame(win)
frame.pack()
win.title('Justin Calculator')


txtdisplay=Entry(frame,textvariable=n1,bd=30,insertwidth=1,font=30)
txtdisplay.pack(side=TOP)

def one():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'1')
def two():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'2')
def three():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'3')
def four():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'4')
def five():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'5')
def six():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'6')
def seven():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'7')
def eight():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'8')
def nine():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,'9')

def action(arg):
    txtdisplay.insert(END,arg)

def add():
    global n1              
    operator='+'
    n1=float(txtdisplay.get())
    txtdisplay.delete(0,END)

def addition(x,y):
        return x+y
        txtdisplay.insert(END,str(addition)(n1+n2)

Topframe=Frame(win)
Topframe.pack(side=TOP)

num1=Button(Topframe,padx=6, pady=6, bd=5, text='1',command=one,fg='blue')
num1.pack(side=LEFT)

num2=Button(Topframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='2',command=two,fg='blue')
num2.pack(side=LEFT)

num3=Button(Topframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='3',command=three,fg='blue')
num3.pack(side=LEFT)

centerframe=Frame(win)
centerframe.pack(side=TOP)
num4=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='4',command=four,fg='red')
num4.pack(side=LEFT)
num5=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='5',command=five,fg='red')
num5.pack(side=LEFT)
num6=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='6',command=six,fg='red')
num6.pack(side=LEFT)

centerframe=Frame(win)
centerframe.pack(side=TOP)
num7=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='7',command=seven,fg='black')
num7.pack(side=LEFT)
num8=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='8',command=eight,fg='black')
num8.pack(side=LEFT)
num9=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='9',command=nine,fg='black')
num9.pack(side=LEFT)

centerframe=Frame(win)
centerframe.pack(side=TOP)
subtraction=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='-',fg='black')
subtraction.pack(side=LEFT)
num0=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='0',fg='black')
num0.pack(side=LEFT)
ExitBtn=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='Exit',command=win.destroy,fg='black')
ExitBtn.pack(side=LEFT)

centerframe=Frame(win)
centerframe.pack(side=TOP)
_add=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='+',command=add,fg='black')
_add.pack(side=LEFT)
subtraction=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='-',fg='black')
subtraction.pack(side=LEFT)
multiplication=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='*',fg='black')
multiplication.pack(side=LEFT)
division=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='/',fg='black')
division.pack(side=LEFT)
_equal=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='=',command=equal,fg='black')
_equal.pack(side=LEFT)

bottomframe=Frame(win)
bottomframe.pack(side=TOP)
clear=Button(bottomframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='Clear')
clear.pack(side=LEFT)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed all the syntax errors. I have commented out your error. There are still some logical errors.

```
from tkinter import Tk,Frame,Entry,Button

#import tkinter

n1=0
n2=0
operator=''

win=Tk()
frame=Frame(win)
frame.pack()
win.title('Justin Calculator')

END='end'
txtdisplay=Entry(frame,textvariable=n1,bd=30,insertwidth=1,font=30)
#why have you added unnecessary indentation?
txtdisplay.pack(side='top')

def one():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,1)
def two():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,2)
def three():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,3)
def four():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,4)
def five():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,5)
def six():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,6)
def seven():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,7)
def eight():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,8)
def nine():
    txtdisplay.insert(END,9)

def action(arg):
    txtdisplay.insert(END,arg)

def add():
    global n1              
    operator='+'
    n1=float(txtdisplay.get())
    txtdisplay.delete(0,END)

def addition(x,y):

    txtdisplay.insert(END,str(addition)(n1+n2))
    return x+y #the statement after return statement will never get executed


Topframe=Frame(win)
Topframe.pack(side='top')

num1=Button(Topframe,padx=6, pady=6, bd=5, text='1',command=one,fg='blue')
num1.pack(side='left')

num2=Button(Topframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='2',command=two,fg='blue')
num2.pack(side='left')

num3=Button(Topframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='3',command=three,fg='blue')
num3.pack(side='left')

# side= LEFT or TOP does not work. follw the dicumentation

centerframe=Frame(win)
centerframe.pack(side='top')
num4=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='4',command=four,fg='red')
num4.pack(side='left')
num5=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='5',command=five,fg='red')
num5.pack(side='left')
num6=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='6',command=six,fg='red')
num6.pack(side='left')

centerframe=Frame(win)
centerframe.pack(side='top')
num7=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='7',command=seven,fg='black')
num7.pack(side='left')
num8=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='8',command=eight,fg='black')
num8.pack(side='left')
num9=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='9',command=nine,fg='black')
num9.pack(side='left')

centerframe=Frame(win)
centerframe.pack(side='top')
subtraction=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='-',fg='black')
subtraction.pack(side='left')
num0=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='0',fg='black')
num0.pack(side='left')
ExitBtn=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='Exit',command=win.destroy,fg='black')
ExitBtn.pack(side='left')

centerframe=Frame(win)
centerframe.pack(side='top')
_add=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='+',command=add,fg='black')
_add.pack(side='left')
subtraction=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='-',fg='black')
subtraction.pack(side='left')
multiplication=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='*',fg='black')
multiplication.pack(side='left')
division=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='/',fg='black')
division.pack(side='left')
_equal=Button(centerframe,padx=6,pady=7,bd=5,text='=',fg='black')
_equal.pack(side='left')

bottomframe=Frame(win)
bottomframe.pack(side='top')
clear=Button(bottomframe,padx=6,pady=6,bd=5,text='Clear')
clear.pack(side='left')

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `textvariable` this way:

```
n1=0
# ...
txtdisplay=Entry(frame,textvariable=n1, ...
```

Using a `textvariable` is a valid way to go about this problem, but mixing access to the `Entry` directly with using a `textvariable` is probably not optimal so let's toss the `textvariable` for now.

This program looks like you built the interface with no thought ahead of time how you were going to make it run.  Below is a rework of your calculator such that "+", "=", and "Clear" now work.  I also threw in a working decimal point.  You should be able to add up numbers, and add to those sums, all you want.  But you'll need to figure out how to implement the remaining operations yourself based on these examples:

```
import operator
from tkinter import *

def zero():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '0')
def one():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '1')
def two():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '2')
def three():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '3')
def four():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '4')
def five():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '5')
def six():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '6')
def seven():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '7')
def eight():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '8')
def nine():
    txtdisplay.insert(END, '9')

def decimal():
    if '.' not in txtdisplay.get():
        txtdisplay.insert(END, '.')

def add():
    global n1, operation
    operation = operator.add
    n1 = float(txtdisplay.get())
    txtdisplay.delete(0, END)

def equal():
    global operation
    n2 = float(txtdisplay.get())
    txtdisplay.delete(0, END)

    if operation:
        txtdisplay.insert(0, str(operation(n1, n2)))
        operation = None

def clear():
    global n1, operation
    n1 = 0.0
    operation = None
    txtdisplay.delete(0, END)

n1 = 0.0
operation = None

win = Tk()
win.title('StackOverflow Calculator')

options = {'padx':6, 'pady':6, 'bd':5}
sticky = {'sticky': (N, S, E, W)}

frame = Frame(win)
frame.pack()

txtdisplay = Entry(frame, bd=30, insertwidth=1, font=30)
txtdisplay.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

Button(frame, text='-', fg='black', **options).grid(row=1, column=3, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='*', fg='black', **options).grid(row=1, column=2, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='/', fg='black', **options).grid(row=1, column=1, **sticky)

Button(frame, text='7', command=seven, fg='black', **options).grid(row=2, column=0, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='8', command=eight, fg='black', **options).grid(row=2, column=1, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='9', command=nine, fg='black', **options).grid(row=2, column=2, **sticky)

Button(frame, text='4', command=four, fg='red', **options).grid(row=3, column=0, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='5', command=five, fg='red', **options).grid(row=3, column=1, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='6', command=six, fg='red', **options).grid(row=3, column=2, **sticky)

Button(frame, text='1', command=one, fg='blue', **options).grid(row=4, column=0, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='2', command=two, fg='blue', **options).grid(row=4, column=1, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='3', command=three, fg='blue', **options).grid(row=4, column=2, **sticky)

Button(frame, text='0', command=zero, fg='black', **options).grid(row=5, column=1, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='.', command=decimal, fg='black', **options).grid(row=5, column=2, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='Exit', command=win.destroy, fg='black', **options).grid(row=5, column=0, **sticky)

Button(frame, text='+', command=add, fg='black', **options).grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=2, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='=', command=equal, fg='black', **options).grid(row=4, column=3, rowspan=2, **sticky)
Button(frame, text='Clear', command=clear, **options).grid(row=1, column=0, **sticky)

win.mainloop()
```

Finally, I rebuilt your interface using a `grid()` manager in a single frame instead of `pack()` and multiple frames.  I'm not suggesting this is how your calculator should be laid out, just that `grid()` may be a better way to go with an interface like this.

[image]